# How to use class functions in another class?

Tags: node.js, class

How can i use class instance in another class like a pointer in C++ to class instance functions?

Example:

```
class A {
    constructor()
    { 
       this.block = [];
    }

    method()
    {
       return this.blocks.length;
    }
}
```

another class:

```
class B {
    constructor(instance)
    { 
       this.instance = instance;
    }

    method()
    {
        this.instance.method(); // here i'm getting cannot get length of undefined
    }
}
```

If i'm trying to to like that i'm getting problems to call it

Comment: It look like `B` expects you to pass in an instance of `A`. If you do that, it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. Here, when creating B class's instance I give into it an A class's instance as argument. Then inside B we can call A instance's methods, and access its properties.

Also, as @ViaTech posted you can use static methods to access them without needing to initialize an object of the class. That is what static methods is. Refer [Static Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

```js
class B {
    constructor(instance)
    {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    method()
    {
        this.instance.method();
    }
}
class A {
    constructor()
    {

    }

    method()
    {
    console.log("A's method");
    }
}

var a = new A();
var b = new B(a);
b.method(); // A's method
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this in JS by calling a static method like so:

```
class A {
  static write(){  //static method
    console.log("Called write from A");
  }
}

class B {
   doIt(){
     A.write();
   }
}


let b = new B();
b.doIt();
```

Option 2, you instantiate the class in the constructor of the other like so:

```
class A {
  write(){
    console.log("Non-static write() called from class A");
  }
}

class B {
   constructor() {
       this.a = new A();
   }

   doIt(){
     this.a.write();
   }
}

let b = new B();
b.doIt();
```

Comment: Oh my bad, I had called the initial class One before making edits to match the OP question. This should have been self explanatory looking at my code

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways:
*<sup>I accidentally switched between PHP and Javascript, but the principles are the same for both)</sup>*

#### Use static functions:

Normally, you have a `this` in the class. Say you have this code:

```
class Car {
    let color;
    public function setColor(newColor){ this.color = newColor;}
}
let car = new Car(); 
car->setColor('green')`
```

The `setColor` function's `this` refers to *that* `car`. You can make `let anotherCar = new Car()`, then when you do `anotherCar->setColor('red')` you only change *that* car, not the first one. Simplistic: You can create multiple instances.

If you do not need that, but need the class once, you can make it static. A simple way to explain would be "you have a collection of seperate functions, just put into a wrapping class (which doesn't do a lot really)". For instance, you might have some sanatizing methods:

```
class Sanitize {
    static function makeHtmlSave(input){
        return doYourMagicHere(input);
    }
    static function removeXssCode(input){
        return doMoreMagicHere(input);
    }
}
```

This way, you can reuse it multiple times. If you want to use it, you do `Sanitize::makeHtmlSave(someCode)` where you need it. There isn't a `Sanitize` *thing*, it's just a wrapper to access the frunctions inside it.

---

#### Use extend:

You can extend a class. Say you have a generic class `Vehicle`, which has some properties (eg a motor, numberWeels, color) and you can extend that with more specific classes:

```
class Vehicle {
    let color;
    public function setColor(newColor){ this.color = newColor}
}
class Car extends Vehicle {
    let hasAirco = false;
    public function hasAirco(newValue){ this.hasAirco = newValue};
}
```

If you do `let car = new Car()`, you get a Car object, that extends/enlarges/complements the Vehicle class, so you can use both its (public) functions. Internally, Car can use the functions of Vehicle too.

---

#### Just pass it

```
class One {
   // some stuff
}

class Two{
    let otherObject;
    construct(givenObject){
        this.otherObject = givenObject;
    }
}
```

You can now do this `let a = new One(); let b = new Two(a);`. You can **not** use the functions of One inside Two, but you can still use `a->doSomething()`. This solution feels like the easiest, but it almost never is. Classes/objects are tricky stuff, but I've rarely uses this solutions. There are use cases, but often it's a *bad smell* indicator.

Comment: Although your answer seems complex, +1 for revealing extend method. Did not think that. :). You may want to simplify your answer

Comment: I tried to keep it simple, but it's difficult to explain it more simple. Im open for suggestions :)

Comment: In "Use static functions:" you may want to revise first paragraph. It is hard to follow, maybe put codes to different lines using code sections

Comment: Changed it a bit. Dont really have time to update it further right now :)